# Migration from VS6 to VS10: 'AfxCrtErrorCheck' in atlmfc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to compile the code originally written in Visual studio 6 to VS 10. 
I read in one of the MSDN article that 'atlmfc' has been removed from VS10. what is the alternative for atlmfc in VS10 ?
error is pointing to atlchecked.h file.

error C2664: 'AfxCrtErrorCheck' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'errno_t'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
.
.
program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(2235): error C2065: 'cVal' : undeclared identifier

These errors are in all the header files like atlcomcli.h, oaidl.h.
**part 1**) I guess that whatever is included in #ifdef has not been recognized in VS10, I might need to give correct path or include relevant header file. Surprisingly no solution on the net so far. If I compare with other solution it doesnt seem to be a problem since path is correct. I am picking all the atlmfc files from visual studio 10 version.
**part 2)** as Scott said code change is required but here the problem it points to is

> #ifdef _AFX
>       #define ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) AFX_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr)
>       #else
>       #define ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) ATL_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr)
>       #endif

One of the article on the net says - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

"#ifdefs in the MFC header files are removed." What does that mean ? if that is removed any alternative for that in Visual studio 10 ?

Also can i directly convert VS6 code to VS10 or should i convert it to VS8 first and then migrate it to VS10 ? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

'atlmfc' is a folder name in the VC directory. It has not been removed in the versions of VC that cost money but it is removed in the "express" version, which is free. You must have a paid-for version of VC to use the MFC and ATL libraries.

I think VS10 will open and convert your VS6 project, although the result will still require you to make code changes.

Comment: thanks Scott, whatever you suggested here has been taken care of. Can you give a small example of what kind of code changes are required ?

Comment: In my experience all of the compatibility problems that arise in this upgrade will cause compile errors. You don't have to search for them: They will be brought to your attention. The most common such error is that in modern C++ when you do for (int I = ...) the I variable is out of scope after the loop. VC6 let you access I after the loop.

Comment: Scott, Thanks for commenting. I have edited the question for your better understanding. I got what you said but since i am not able to compile i am unable to debug and reach a place where a loop or condition is breaking. I just want my code to compile for now. I do have paid version of VS10.

Comment: Also if you can suggest any reference material on the net which can suggest required changes ?

Comment: In the "breaking changes" page that you linked to you can select the similar documents for VS 2008, 2010 and 2012. It would be good to review all of them.

Comment: When we removed __STDC__, from project properties -> preprocessor the mentioned errors disappeared. But I think we will need __STDC__since the project is using lot of C files too. Of course there are other new errors. What could be the relation between __STDC____ and above errors Scoot ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, direct conversion from visual studio 6 to VS10 is not possible. Why will microsoft allow that ? :)
we have to go through VS5 and then VS10.
also the conversion is gonna be extraordinarily difficult with lot of code changes.
http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/28908